# Why is velocity returning zero? In C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define GRAVITY 9.8

double mag(double x, double y, double z);
double metersFallen(double fallTime);
double velocity (double v, double t1, double t2, double magAcc);
double position (double x, double v, double t1, double t2);

int main()
{
    printf("Ok, I'm now receiving data.\n");

    int running = TRUE;
    double secFall = 0;;
    double distance = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int programStartTime = 0;
    double currentTime = 0;
    int time = 0;
    int start = 0, end = 0;
    double x, y, z, v, p;
    double seconds;

    scanf("%d,%lf,%lf,%lf", &time, &x, &y, &z);
    printf("I'm Waiting");
    programStartTime = time;
    seconds = time;

    while(running){

        scanf("%d,%lf,%lf,%lf", &time, &x, &y, &z);

        if((time - programStartTime) >= 1000){

            printf(".");
            programStartTime = time;

        }   

        if(mag(x, y, z) < .75 ){

            start = time;
            printf("Help me! I'm falling");

            while(end == 0){

                if((time - programStartTime) >= 1000){

                    printf("!");
                    programStartTime = time;
                }

                scanf("%d,%lf,%lf,%lf", &time, &x, &y, &z);

                v = velocity(v, time, seconds, mag(x,y,z));
                p = position(x, v, time, seconds);
                seconds = time;

                if(mag(x, y, z) > .95 ){

                    end = time;
                    running = FALSE;
                }
                fflush(stdout);
            }
        }
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    secFall = ((end - start)/1000.0);
    distance = metersFallen(secFall);
    //percent = ; 

    printf("\nTime falling was %6.3lf seconds\n", secFall);
    printf("Distance fallen was %6.3lf meters\n", distance);
    printf("Compensating for air resistance, the fall was %lf meters.\n", p);
    //printf("This is %lf less than computed before\n", percent);
    printf("%lf\n", mag(x,y,z));

    return 0;

}

double metersFallen(double fallTime)
{  

    return(.5*GRAVITY*fallTime*fallTime);

}
double mag(double x, double y, double z)
{

    return sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);

}
double velocity (double v, double t1, double t2, double magAcc)
{
    int numVelocity = v + GRAVITY*(1-magAcc)*(t1 - t2)/1000;
    return numVelocity;
}
double position (double x, double v, double t1, double t2)
{
    double p = x + v*(t1 - t2)/1000;
    return p;
}
```

Running with this sample data 
http://www.filedropper.com/lab6sampledata20131

I need the position function to work, but with Velocity returning zero I cannot. We are using a device with an accelerometer to run this. FYI I am a student who is fairly new to programming please be patient.

Comment: `int numVelocity` - change to `double numVelocity`.

Comment: `#define TRUE 1 ...` **Don't!** Use proper boolean types and the values. See `stdbool.h`!

Comment: My skeleton code from my professor included the  `#define TRUE 1` so I have to leave it for now.

Answer (score 2):

Your velocity function is almost certainly returning 0 because you have defined `numVelocity` as an `int`.

In C, when doing computations on integers, the answer will always be rounded down to the nearest integer and as your time steps are on the order of 5, your second term is going to be close to 0. Adding this to something close to 0 will round down to 0.

You also haven't initialised `v` as far as I can tell and you are passing `v` (unitialised) into your velocity function to compute `v` which will give you undefined results (most likely 0...).

Also, when doing calculations in double precision, you should write constants with a decimal point of 0 I.e. `1000.0`. That is interpreted as a double by the program rather than `1000` which is an int.

Likewise, time is an integer variable and you have requested that it is a double in your function. You can cast it to do this by passing `(double)time` instead of `time`.

Try changing these things in your code (initialise v by setting it to your initial velocity) and see what changes :)

Comment: I have `v` initialized as a double.

Comment: Yes that defines the type but it currently has no value :D!

saying double v; doesn't give v a value.
What happens now if you try to add 1 to it? We don't know because we don't know what we're adding 1 to. It could be anything.

You need to write double v=0; to start with (or whatever your initial velocity is) then we can add 1 to it (for instance) because we now know what we're adding 1 to

Comment: No problem, you can get your compiler to tell you useful things like this.

If you're using GCC for instance, adding -Wall to the compilation command will let you know about various type issues, unused variables, use of uninitialised variables etc :)

Comment: Oh that is great to know because I use gcc. Also, how would I go about calculating the `percent` that is commented out?

Comment: Percent difference between the distances?

Comment: If so, you'll need to store the previous distance in a variable too so you have both. (And you'll also need to define a double percent; variable).

So you can do something like oldDistance = distance; distance = metersFallen(secFall);
percent = 100.0 * (distance - oldDistance)/oldDistance

Comment: Ok I will try that. Also, for my `p` I am getting an output of `-0.115393 meters` which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Also for the percent instead of using `oldDistance` wouldn't I just use `distance` for the old one and `p` as the new one?

Comment: Hmm no that doesn't seem right. Try the same tricks again and make sure your times are actually doubles and type the numerical constants with a decimal point. If that doesn't work, you'll have to try and stick some print statements in your functions to print out what the values are, and then compare them with what you think they should be from your input file. That will narrow down where it's going wrong :).


As for the percent, sure it depends what you're calculating the percentage of. You know what your variables are better than us :).

Comment: So you are saying `int time = 0;` should be `double time = 0.0;`?

Comment: That's one way of doing it, but that would require a few rewrites to your scanf functions. The easy way is to just pass `(x, v, (double)time, seconds);` to your function instead of `(x, v, time, seconds);`